# update multi table simultaneously in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a queries like these below and I need it to be in a single update query. As I'm a beginner I use joins and wrote the single line query but I get error as

> Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Here below is the each Individual update query...

```
update a set id=id-1 where id>'3' and reg='34554';
update b set id=id-1 where id>'3' and reg='34554';
update c set id=id-1 where id>'3' and reg='34554';
update d set id=id-1 where id>'3' and reg='34554';
update e set id=id-1 where id>'3' and reg='34554';
```

Here below is what I tried out and got error as told above...

```
update a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id=a.id and b.tan=a.tan
LEFT JOIN c ON c.id=b.id and c.tan=b.tan
LEFT JOIN d ON d.id=c.id and d.tan=c.tan
LEFT JOIN e ON e.id=d.id and e.tan=d.tan
SET a.id=b.id=c.id=d.id=e.id=a.id-1
where a.id>'3' and a.tan='34554';
```

Comment: are a,b,c,d,e different tables?

Comment: yes, they are different tables

Comment: How long do the individual queries take to execute? Please add the output from `SHOW INDEXES` for each of the tables to your question. You should remove the quotes from your integer values.

Comment: It takes very less time only, but I need it in a single query because I use this in java class. In my java code for each and every update I need to write a set of preparedStatement, which increases my lines of code more. If I use a single line SQL statement, then I can use only one preparedStatement so My code is reduced.

Comment: SHOW INDEXES is showing nothing i.e empty and  dont know well how to use update along with joins so I tried some.

Comment: yes, I did it for each table, since I did't give any constrains it shows an empty result and I dont understand what you mean by resequencing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store multiple sql in Stored procedures then call the procedure from java.. Id & reg can be passed thro parameters.

Info on stored procedures http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

You have to do this  in Mysql command line...

```
Delimiter |

Create procedure (in id_val int, in reg_val int)

Begin

update a set id=id-1 where id>id_val and reg=reg_val;

update b set id=id-1 where id>id_val and reg=reg_val;

update c set id=id-1 where id>id_val and reg=reg_val;

update d set id=id-1 where id>id_val and reg=reg_val;

update e set id=id-1 where id>id_val and reg=reg_val;

End |

delimiter ;
```

I use PHP... info in following link
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Hope of java... this link may be useful
http://www.easywayserver.com/jdbc/JDBC-prepared-statement.htm

Comment: Good Idea. But how do I use it in my preparedStatement? Do I need to use BatchUpdate?

Comment: I think you left out procedure's name in your answer.

Comment: @nnichols I have a doubt whether my update statement with joins will work or not. If update and joins can be used then what is gone wrong in my insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use transactions

```
SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES a WRITE, b WRITE, c WRITE, d WRITE, e WRITE

update a set id=id-1 where id>'3' and reg='34554';
update b set id=id-1 where id>'3' and reg='34554';
update c set id=id-1 where id>'3' and reg='34554';
update d set id=id-1 where id>'3' and reg='34554';
update e set id=id-1 where id>'3' and reg='34554';

COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

You can read  about combining lock tables with transactions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html)

I don't know, how to create such query with join.

Comment: is this work like a single query rather  i think it will more complicate it.

Comment: Cant we do it with some joins? instead of using individual update statement?

Comment: I have already used java code for setting autocommit to false. so shall I use your code without SET autocommit=0 and commit ?

Comment: I don't know how frameworks in java are handling transactions. Sorry;/.

Comment: Using the Connector/J methods will have the same effect as running these statements in SQL directly.